# Problems when calling an external program from R in docker

Tags: r, docker, shiny, phantomjs

I have some issue when I try to use webshot in a shiny app inside a docker container.
depending on how I organise the shinyapp sometimes it works well sometime it doesn't.

I create a little reprex (Dockerfile + R package)containing 2 fonctions, 
using [run_app2](https://github.com/VincentGuyader/webshotdocker/blob/d0c4a03531dfd4dc46b2c6ebbd660e73b6425055/R/run_app.R#L30) everything is ok , I can have a png file from a dygraph
using [run_app](https://github.com/VincentGuyader/webshotdocker/blob/d0c4a03531dfd4dc46b2c6ebbd660e73b6425055/R/run_app.R#L15) the call to phantomjs is stuck at the begining. and nothing happend

`webshot` launch this kind of instruction (using the `callr` package):

`/usr/local/bin/phantomjs --ignore-ssl-errors=true /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/webshot/webshot.js [{"url":"/tmp/RtmpIObg1n/dygraph8103063cd.html","file":"/tmp/RtmpIObg1n/file84a4d60a.png","vwidth":992,"vheight":744,"delay":0.2,"zoom":1,"debug":true}]`

using `run_app2`, everything is fine, but with `run_app` phantomjs can't manage to start !

using the unix `strace`  function inside the container I found this error showing that phantomjs is endless looking for something on the top of the folder (again and again):

[image: strace phantomjs output]

To run the reprex please use this Dockerfile

```
FROM rocker/tidyverse

RUN apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jre && R CMD javareconf
RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y htop strace nano bzip2
RUN R -e 'install.packages("remotes")'
RUN R -e 'install.packages("pacman")'
RUN R -e "pacman::p_load('webshot')"
RUN R -e 'webshot::install_phantomjs()'
RUN R -e "pacman::p_load('dygraphs')"
RUN R -e "pacman::p_load('shiny')"
RUN echo 'local({options(shiny.port = 3838, shiny.host = "0.0.0.0")})' >> /usr/local/lib/R/etc/Rprofile.site
RUN R -e 'remotes::install_github("VincentGuyader/webshotdocker")'
EXPOSE 3838
CMD R -e 'reprexsnapshot::run_app()'
```

Then

```
docker build -t reprex .
```

And then

```
 # OK
 docker run  -p 80:3838 reprex R -e 'reprexsnapshot::run_app2()'

 # not OK
 docker run  -p 80:3838 reprex R -e 'reprexsnapshot::run_app()'
```

Tips : you can add `-cap-add=SYS_PTRACE --security-opt seccomp=unconfined` to be able to use strace inside the container

I spent several hours on this case to understand and delimit the problem, I really don't understand what's going on. I would be very grateful if someone could dig into this case with me.

Comment: I had good experience with the `rize` package: https://github.com/cole-brokamp/rize. See my shiny app here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TagAnomaly